# Мне нужно сделать вложенный список в каждом элементе списка, состоящего из строковых символов

Tags: python, строки, list

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alphabet = list(alphabet)
counter = 0
for letter in alphabet:
    alphabet[counter][0] = counter
```

хочу сделать так, чтобы при вызове alphabet[n][0] выводило числа от 1 до 25
При выполнении моего варианта вылетает ТайпЭрор, говорящий о том, что нельзя сделать из стринговой переменной список.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите, пример списка, который должен получиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

alphabet = list(alphabet)

for i, v in enumerate(alphabet):
    print(i, v)
```

---

**Update**

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alphabet = list(alphabet)

for i, v in enumerate(alphabet):
    alphabet[i] = i, v


print(alphabet[4][0])       # 4
print(alphabet[4][1])       # e
```

Comment: Мне нужно запомнить значение, потому enumerate не подходит

Comment: @ArtyomLazovikov  покажите что вы хотите получить

Comment: Это именно то, что мне было нужно, благодарю, так странно, что я до этого не допёр сам

Comment: @ArtyomLazovikov если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, не забудьте отметить его как правильный.